# Rerun function when hidden element is displayed on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, filter

- I have a function that checks if all my form fields have been filled
  in, if they have it removes the disabled attribute on my submit
  button and allows the user to submit.
- This works perfectly, however, I have a field that only appears if a
  certain element is selected in one of the drop-downs on the page,
  when this element appears I add the validate class on like so:

  ```
  if (job.value === "OTHER") {
      $('#inputOtherJobFunction').parent().show();
      $('#inputOtherJobFunction').addClass('validate');
  } else {
      $('#inputOtherJobFunction').removeClass('validate);
  }
  ```

I then assign the $fieldsToCheck variable again within my function so it now includes the new form element on the screen.

After this new element appears on the screen, the disabled button only becomes active when I click into another input box and type something.

I am thinking I need to trigger this function everytime anything is entered on my form, but I am not quite sure.

```
let $registerButton = $('.create-account-button');
let $fieldsToCheck = $('.registration-form .validate');

let checkFields = function () {
    $fieldsToCheck = $('.registration-form .validate');
    console.log('being called');
    let emptyFields = $fieldsToCheck.map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get().filter(function (val) {
        return val.length === 0;
    });
    $registerButton.prop('disabled', !!emptyFields.length);
};

$fieldsToCheck.blur(checkFields);
checkFields();
```

Comment: Just call once more to `checkFields();` when you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried that?

```
if (job.value === "OTHER") {
            $('#inputOtherJobFunction').parent().show();
            $('#inputOtherJobFunction').addClass('validate');

            checkFields();
        } else {
            $('#inputOtherJobFunction').removeClass('validate);
        }
```

Edit:
Understanding your needs by your comment I'd say try attaching the method to the relevant events.

```
$fieldsToCheck.on('focus blur change', checkFields);
```

Your case might require just `focus` and `blur`

Comment: I tried this, I think it's more down the $fieldsToCheck.blur, i think maybe blur is the wrong thing to use, but i'm not sure

Comment: It's working on every case, except when I choose the element in the dropdown that gives me the new field, if I clear the text box that appears, I have to click in another input box until the button is not disabled, are there more things I can put in .on() ?

Comment: @NickPocock Basically every input event, such as `keypress`, `keyup`.

Though in your case it sounds like you need to attach `change` event listener on your selectbox and do what you want (i.e call `checkFields()`) in the callback.